# Inject implementation from config file

Tags: c#, .net

I have one interface "`IBigData`" (in Gik.Interface.dll)

Two classes implementing IBigData interface: 
`Hadoop` (in Gik.Data.Hadoop.dll assembly) 
`Azure` (in Gik.Data.Azure.dll assembly)

We have one main class (in Gik.Processor.dll assembly) that contains the switch case which defines when to execute which implementation.

**QUESTION**: 
Whenever we have new implementation we have to update our main class switch case. 
Can it be done via app.config/web.config file?

```
<ImplementedAssembly>
    <Assembly>Gik.Data.Hadoop.dll</Assembly>
    <Assembly>Gik.Data.Aws.dll</Assembly>
    <Assembly>Gik.Data.Azure.dll</Assembly>
 </ImplementedAssembly>
```

Comment: Yup - you should be using something like Unity framework, Windsor Castle, or some similar dependency injection framework. The two I mentioned both support a configuration-driven approach. They also support the concept of run-time assembly loading and dependency injection. Which means that you simply drop the DLL into a given folder, and it "just works", if you write the appropriate code.

Comment: Really!!! it is possible. you made my day. Could you share the sample code, if you have?

Comment: Try to use dependency injection library like Autofac, here is a link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25380/Dependency-Injection-with-Autofac